AutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener with Custom Adapter doesnt'work
I'm trying to re-build a small test application to test the AutoCompleteTextView and its features. The first step is to create a Custom Adapter to display a textview and a checkbox next to each other. The intent is to do a search and select the item found in the search space from the AutoCompleteTextview, but I have made several attempts, but it doesn't work. When I try to select the find string, the setOnClickListener does nothing.. In the code below I used a constraintlayout, but even with the linearlayout, I get the same result.
public class SelectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    List<String> itemsAdapter;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SelectAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
        super(context, 0, textViewResourceId, objects);
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayList<>(objects);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return itemsAdapter.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.url_row, parent, false);
        }

        String item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        CheckBox checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        textView.setText(item);
        checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return convertView;

    }

}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> listaurl = new ArrayList<>();
    AutoCompleteTextView act;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listaurl.add("Orange");
        listaurl.add("Apple");
        listaurl.add("Mango");

        act = findViewById(R.id.idFilterItem);

        SelectAdapter sa = new SelectAdapter(this,R.id.idFilterItem,listaurl);
        act.setAdapter(sa);
        act.requestFocus();

        act.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
            String selectedItem = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            act.setText(selectedItem);
        });
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Any suggestions for resolution are welcome

You might want to expand on what "it does nothing mean" and indicate what you have done to debug. Have you put print statements or breakpoints instead the listener? Is it not being invoked at all, or it is and setText is not working?
